# JQuery - How do I make so it scrolls to the div but -70px?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I have this code that I use on my website, I use the script below for my navigation system, but I have a fixed navigation bar on the top of the screen and it's 70px height, so I need to make the script so it gets to the div but -70px so I can see the top of the div.

When I click on Portfolio and Contact I can't see the entire div because of the navigation bar, how can I fix this problem?.

Thanks for all the help :D

```
var wrap_contactPosition = jQuery('.wrap_contact').offset().top;
jQuery('.nav_contact').click(function(){
    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:wrap_contactPosition}, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var wrap_contactPosition = jQuery('.wrap_contact').offset().top;
jQuery('.nav_contact').click(function(){
    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:wrap_contactPosition + 70}, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Just a note, you may want to use something like $('#nav').height() instead of the fixed number for maintainability